# Ripple.js navigator.geolocation.clearWatch

Tags: blackberry, ripple

the following raises and error:

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(gpsWatchId);
```

the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'intervalId' of undefined ripple.js:478
u.clearWatch ripple.js:478
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also getting this error and I've reported the issue here: 
https://github.com/blackberry/Ripple-UI/issues/629

I've seen this error in a variety of situations, most recently as a result of a call to blackberry.event.addEventListener(). So I don't think it's your code. Maybe you could provide the details of your specific situation at the url above to help the ripple-ui developers resolve the issue?

Comment: I'll do it, basically I'm  getting the error in the geolocation.watchPosition error callback function.